# <asp:Button text jerks in IE8+

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, ascx

The text inside the button jerks or moves down by few pixels.

```
<div>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" CssClass="ButtonClass" Text="" runat="server" />
</div>
```

ascx.cs:

```
Button1.Text = LocalizationResourceManager.GetLocalizedValue("Button_Text");
```

CSS:

```
.ButtonClass{
 background: url('/Button.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 33px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-right: 19px;
 width: 180px;
 border: solid 0px;
 color: #fff!important;
 background-position: 0px -31px;
}
```

If there was `<span>`, however, I could have used:

`{position:relative;top;0;left:0;}`

Since `span` cannot be used inside of `asp:button`, I want to have a fix for this button itself.

I tried:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonClass">
    <span runat="server" id="ButtonText"></span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

ascx.cs:

```
 ButtonText.text = LocalizationResourceManager.GetLocalizedValue("Button_Text");
```

I am having error:
`Error  9   'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does your css even apply the button?

Comment: What is the problem. Why am I having minus votes. Even if I give more data, is it a  problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you CSS actually is applied to the button but if you would like to use span inside a button why not change your control to a linkbutton like so:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="Button1">
<span>Register 2</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Edit:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="Button1">
<span>
<asp:Label ID="ButtonText" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I think this should work for you.

Comment: instead of trying to use the span tag server side wrap a label control inside i shall update my answer.